# How can I update a inner property using the 10gen c# driver?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, 10gen-csharp-driver

I have this structure:

```
public class User
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastAround {get;set;}
}

public class Location
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried a few things but I want to update User's Location and when they were last around.

Tried this:

```
userHelper.Collection.Update(
    Query.EQ("_id", userId),
    Update.SetWrapped<Location>("Location", new Location { Latitude = latitude, Longitude = longitude }).Set("LastAround", DateTime.UtcNow));
```

and this:

```
userHelper.Collection.Update(
    Query.EQ("_id", userId),
    Update.Set("Location.Latitude", latitude)
        .Set("Location.Longitude", longitude)
        .Set("LastAround", DateTime.UtcNow));
```

Nothing worked...how can I do this?

**Update 4/17:**

```
userHelper.Collection.Update(
                Query.EQ("_id", new ObjectId(userId)),
                Update
                    .SetWrapped<Location>("Location", new Location { Longitude = longitude, Latitude = latitude })
                    .Set("LastAround", DateTime.UtcNow)
            );
```

The lng and lat value orders seem to be very important when doing queries on them. I was doing a geonear query and getting an strange out of bounds error. If you update in the wrong order it will put lats first and then you get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your original Update statements should work. I wrote a small sample program to demonstrate.

After executing this Insert statement:

```
var userId = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
var user = new User
{
    Id = userId,
    Location = new Location { Latitude = 1.0, Longitude = 2.0 },
    LastAround = new DateTime(2012, 4, 14, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
};
collection.Insert(user);
```

The document looks like this in the mongo shell:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f8c5d33e447ad34b8c7ac84"), "Location" : { "Latitude" : 1, "Longitude" : 2 }, "LastAround" : ISODate("2012-04-14T00:00:00Z") }
>
```

After executing the first form of the Update statement:

```
collection.Update(
    Query.EQ("_id", userId),
    Update
        .SetWrapped<Location>("Location", new Location { Latitude = 3.0, Longitude = 4.0 })
        .Set("LastAround", new DateTime(2012, 4, 15, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)));
```

the document looks like this:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f8c5d33e447ad34b8c7ac84"), "Location" : { "Latitude" : 3, "Longitude" : 4 }, "LastAround" : ISODate("2012-04-15T00:00:00Z") }
>
```

And after executing the second form of the Update statement:

```
collection.Update(
    Query.EQ("_id", userId),
    Update
        .Set("Location.Latitude", 5.0)
        .Set("Location.Longitude", 6.0)
        .Set("LastAround", new DateTime(2012, 4, 16, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)));
```

the document looks like this:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f8c5d33e447ad34b8c7ac84"), "Location" : { "Latitude" : 5, "Longitude" : 6 }, "LastAround" : ISODate("2012-04-16T00:00:00Z") }
>
```

So the two forms of the Update statement are working.

The full program is here:

http://www.pastie.org/3799469

Comment: Strange, I have no idea why mine wasn't working. I have learned since though the for geo queries the lat and lng need to switch positions with the lng being first.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your alternatives look ok.

Are you sure that your userId variable had the correct value? It could be that the Update is not finding a matching document to update.

Comment: Yeah, everything looked ok. Couldn't get the update statement to work though.

Comment: If your userId variable was of type string and you weren't converting it to an ObjectId in the call to Query.EQ then Find would not have found the matching document (because a string can't equal an ObjectId). So it seems likely that your Update wasn't doing the update because the query wasn't matching any document.

Comment: That could be it, let me look again and try. userId is a string so that's entirely likely. I think I did var id = new ObjectId(userId) other places so I'll give that a whirl. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing:

```
var userHelper = new MongoHelper<User>();
ObjectId id = new ObjectId(userId);
var user = userHelper.Collection.FindAll().Where(u => u.Id == id).Single();
user.LastAround = DateTime.UtcNow;
user.Location = new Location { Longitude = longitude, Latitude = latitude };
userHelper.Collection.Save(user);
```

which works. Not sure why the other way wouldn't. I suppose this is more "SQL" like although might not have the best performance. :(

Comment: There is a problem with this code, because FindAll is returning *all* the documents from the server, and then you are using a client-side Where to find the one you want to update. See the new answer I started with sample code.

Comment: The FindAll isn't IQueryable? How would I properly do this command then in other cases? In either case, I'll try switching it when I get home tonight. I didn't see your replies till today.

Comment: FindAll is IEnumerable, so the Where clause is executed client side. You can create a query using Query.EQ("_id", id) and pass it as an argument to Find. Or you can call collection.AsQueryable<User>().Where(u => u.Id = id) to use LINQ to MongoDB.